# Ubuntu Multiple Monitor Support

Tags: ati, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have recently aquired a Dell Inspiron 15R Special Edition (7520) and I am trying to get 2 monitors connected, plus the laptop screen. With a single monitor I can have things working no problem, but when two monitors are connected the 2nd one does not work, it receives no signal. If I swap around the monitors, I can have any combination of two working, even both monitors with no laptop screen.

Is there a way I can have my display extended across all three displays, without having to purchase a $300 Matrox triple head device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is no, there is a Hardware limitation to only support two monitors simultaneously.

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19510194.aspx